# C - 'malloc' doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int *arr = NULL;
   arr = (int *) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
   arr[0] = 4;
   arr[1] = 2;
   printf("%d%d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Why does it return 42? isn't the `malloc` size only making one integer available for
 storage? (When I try to arr[1] isn't it supposed to throw an error?)

*I'm using Win7 32 bit*

Comment: It is undefined. You are just accessing some random memory space and read as an integer. It doesn not necessarily throw an error, but commonly give you some weird result.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to arr[1] isn't it supposed to through an error

It doesn't **have to** but it **might**. That's the beauty of undefined behavior in C, there's no telling what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your program causes undefined behaviour, so *anything* can happen, including the appearance of correct behaviour.  You're just overwriting the end of the memory you requested.  After that, all bets are off.  You might be overwriting nothing, or maybe some `malloc` bookkeeping data, or who knows what.  Just don't do that.

Comment: I tried that to learn about the malloc function, not to use it for 'real'.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you've tried won't teach you anything useful.  Undefined behaviour is a dangerous place to tread.